# Class 'Metrakit\Disqus\DisqusServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, composer-php, disqus, service-provider

I have followed this https://packagist.org/packages/metrakit/disqus-laravel for the configuration of disqus with Laravel 4.2.

Since the following command has not worked for me `composer require metrakit/disqus-laravel`, So I have used `composer require metrakit/disqus-laravel "dev-master"` and followed the rest instruction as per given. I am facing this error since morning.

Someone please take me out of this. Thanks.

Comment: Do You added service provider to `app.php` file?

Comment: Yes I have added service provider as well as alias provider. Thanks

Comment: Did you run `composer dumpauto` after installation?

Comment: I have been trying `composer dumpautoload` since morning and just now tried `composer dumpauto` But not worked. Thanks.

Comment: Can you let us know the sequence of steps that you followed for the same ?

Comment: Initially I had followed the steps in the same order as given in the link with only one change that I have mentioned above in the question. Later as it had not worked out for me I used several commands like `composer update` , `composer dumpauto` etc. Thanks

Comment: You are doing something wrong but I can not tell what. Can You attach `composer.json`? And when did You receive this error?

Comment: Thanks Giedrius. Now let's start it again from very first step - `composer require metrakit/disqus-laravel` and the error that i faced in the terminal is - `[InvalidArgumentException] Could not find package metrakit/disqus-laravel at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability`.

Comment: Follow installation guide provided at the bottom of the page in https://packagist.org/packages/metrakit/disqus-laravel . They are saying that You should use "dev-master" package version.